# What is the typeof(Symbol()) in ES6?

Tags: javascript, symbols

So, all we have the `console line` and we can debug the `typeof(Symbol())` in it. But what we get - it's `symbol`. As we know we have the several types of the data in JS:

`string, boolean, number` - primitives;

`undefined` - special non-classed;

`null` - object (special subclass of object);

`object` - object;

`function` - function (special subclass of object).

So and for what group of these types in JS correspond the `Symbols` and why?

Some anwers in the network says, that it has a primitive behavior, but without explaine why...

Comment: The type _is_ `symbol`. It is a primitive type.

Comment: It is of type symbol, a new type :P

Comment: Why , explaine please? @Xufox

Comment: Explain what?, what problem are you trying to solve..?

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the Symbols logic. @Keith

Comment: A symbol is a primitive like a boolean or a string. That is all there is to understand.

Comment: Here is [MDN  Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMAScript 2015 defines [a Symbol as its own kind of primitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-symbol-type):

> **4.3.25 Symbol value**
>
> primitive value that represents a unique, non-String Object property key

Compare this language to the specification's definitions for string and number types, and you'll see it's the standard way the specification defines primitive types:

> **4.3.17 String value**
> primitive value that is a finite ordered sequence of zero or more 16-bit unsigned integer

and

> **4.3.20 Number value**
> primitive value corresponding to a double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754-2008 value

Answer (score 2):

The "symbol" datatype is a primitive itself. You'll see it listed below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive